# Tag for switching/moving to CiviCRM from other systems?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked questions about moving to CiviCRM from a different CRM system. I tagged them with `migration` now, but the tag description is targeted at something else:

> Moving CiviCRM from one server to another, including cloning, changing domains or install locations etc.

Is there a tag for this or should maybe a new one be added?

Answer (score 3):

At this writing, there are 30 questions returned for a search on `migration is:question`. By my reckoning, these break down into three broad categories:

- 4 about using CiviCRM while moving from one CMS to another (what the documentation is usually describing when *migrating* is mentioned)
- 20 about moving a CiviCRM installation from one server to another (what the documentation generally calls *moving*)
- 6 about moving to CiviCRM from a different CMS platform, or from none (the processes of *transitioning* or *adopting*)

None of these terms is especially precise, but I would suggest we use **[transitioning](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transitioning)** to cover moving to or from CiviCRM from another CRM system or process. While the term is used in the book to refer to the process of moving to CiviCRM, rather than about the selection process, it has also been the title of the relevant CiviCon sessions, e.g. *[Introduction and transitioning to CiviCRM](https://london2014.civicrm.org/sessions/introduction-and-transitioning-civicrm)*.